Compose Multiplatform UI test in Android opens the permissions activity and sticks
I have a library that uses KMP + CMP. I want to cover the UI part with tests. for this purpose I modified the build.gradle in the following way
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.cocoapods)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.compose)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.io.realm.kotlin)
    alias(libs.plugins.maven.publish)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        instrumentedTestVariant {
            sourceSetTree = KotlinSourceSetTree.test
        }
    }
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()
    applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()

    jvmToolchain(17)

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
            implementation(libs.realm)
            implementation(libs.decomposeCompose)
            implementation(libs.decompose)
            implementation(libs.datetime)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.uuid)
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.activity.compose)
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test"))
            @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
            implementation(compose.uiTest)
        }
        androidInstrumentedTest.dependencies {
            implementation(project.dependencies.platform(libs.compose.bom))
            implementation(libs.ui.test.junit4.android)
        }
    }
}

android {
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }
    namespace = "com.idfinance.logkmpanion"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(libs.ui.test.manifest)
    }
}

And created tests inside the module/commonTest folder
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
class RootViewTest {

    @Test
    fun rootViewPresents() = runComposeUiTest {
        setContent {
            RootView(
                ServiceLocator.getRootComponent(
                    context = DefaultComponentContext(LifecycleRegistry()),
                    onClose = {}
                )
            )
        }

        onNodeWithTag(RootViewTestTags.ROOT_VIEW).isDisplayed()
    }

    @Test
    fun tabsSwitched() = runComposeUiTest {
        setContent {
            RootView(
                ServiceLocator.getRootComponent(
                    context = DefaultComponentContext(LifecycleRegistry()),
                    onClose = {}
                )
            )
        }

        onNodeWithText("Network logs").performClick()
        onNodeWithTag(NetworkLogsTestTags.ROOT_VIEW).assertExists()
        onNodeWithTag(AllLogsTestTags.ROOT_VIEW).assertDoesNotExist()

        onNodeWithText("All logs").performClick()
        onNodeWithTag(AllLogsTestTags.ROOT_VIEW).assertExists()
        onNodeWithTag(NetworkLogsTestTags.ROOT_VIEW).assertDoesNotExist()
    }
}

But when I launch the ./gradlew :moduleName:connectedAndroidTest tests are stuck and the following activity is opened in emulator

version of compose-bom I use:
compose-bom = "2024.11.00"
Can u please help to me to run the instrumented tests in Android? Thanks in advance for any help!
